# Как правильно вернуть значение в функцию после ajax запроса jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с небольшой задачкой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вернуть значение в функцию? Вот пример кода:

```js
var searchSku = function(val){
  var path = "/search.json?q=",
      sku  = val;
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: path + val,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function($data) {
      var b = $data.id; //тут мы получаем значение
    },
  });

  // как вернуть это значение?
  return
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. ответ приходит в формате JSON, сначала его нужно разобрать с помощью [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
var searchSku = function(val) {
  var path = "/search.json?q=";

  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: path + val,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function($data) {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      switch (data.code) {
        case 200:
          deferred.resolve((JSON.parse($data)).id);
          break;
        default:
          deferred.reject();
          break;
      }

      return deferred.promise();

    }
  });
};
```

Использование:

```
$.when(searchSku("text"))
  .then( function(data){
     alert(data); // $data.id
 });
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но нужно вернуть в функцию searchSku(), в данном примере return возвращает в дочернюю функцию только

Comment: @Виктор В функцию вернуть нельзя, можно вернуть только как результат выполнения функции. Дополнил ответ работой с [промисами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), возможно, в таком стиле функция будет более удобной в работе.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

используем async:false и старый добрый eval

```
var searchSku = function(val){
  var path = "/search.json?q=",
      sku  = val,
      b;
  $.ajax({
    url: path + val,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    async:false,
    success: function(data) {
      b = eval('('+data+')'); //тут мы получаем значение
    },
  });

  // просто возвращаем
  return b.id;
};
```